# Stability of RPI4 USB3 for NAS?

Tags: storage

I currently have an Intel NUC connected to a USB-C RAID1 enclosure. I've been running this for two years without problems. I'd like to replace the Intel NUC with a RPI4, connecting the USB-C port of the enclosure to a USB3 on the RPI4 with a 5Gbps cable (USB-C on one side, USB-A on the other side)

If you have experience attempting to use a RPI4 to run a full-time NAS using a USB3-connected RAID enclosure, could you comment on the stability of the USB port of the RPI4 running Raspbian?

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245931) sticky on the raspberrypi.org forum, which addresses issues with USB3 enclosures and adapters on the Rpi4. The topic title seems as if it is about SSD enclosures, but replies mention HDDs as well. I have to say that, much as I admire Stack Exchange, there are some benefits to joining and reading the raspberrypi.org forum.

Comment: What is a NUC ?

Comment: Next Unit of Computing (NUC) is a line of small-form-factor barebone computer kits designed by Intel. You could have Googled for that information.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey When you have to google to understand the meaning of questions (e.g. abbreviations, datasheets, model numbers) it puts people off answering questions.

Comment: The question isn't about the NUC, directly. The OP could just have written "a computer" instead.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for the link. It's what I needed.

Comment: @joan I provided context in the first paragraph. The question is in the second paragraph. You probably could've inferred that NUC was a computer, couldn't you? And, did you mean to say that you couldn't understand the question itself, the line with the question mark? What's wrong with you?